# OpenCV Hough Cicle Transform sort storage vector

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

I i having a problem Hough Circle Transform. Could anybody explain me how this transform sort the output array?

Comment: Probably in order of detection. Whatever that means ;) if you need it in a special order you should sort it that way.

Comment: I have six circles, two by two are at a small distance. I want to sort them by destance between centers.

Comment: You already have this question posted. Edit it if something has changed, don't post duplicates please.

Comment: "sort them by destance between centers" isnt well described because if there are 6 circles, each of them has 5 distances to different centers... instead of sorting you want to detect "pairs"?

Comment: Yes I want to detecr pairs!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem explicited

I wrote a code that find the center of mass like below:

- I have 6 circles, everyone with his center mass
- I need to group two by two and find the half of the distance between centers of mass
- In this phase I have three points
- Making the average oh this three points i determine a center of mass

I don't understan how could i sort the vecter where are stored the date of the circles.

**Exemple 1**
[image: Here the indices are ok]

**Exmple 2**
[image: Here they don't have an order]

**And here is my code**

```
int loadMyFrameWithHough (string framePath){

Mat myFrame1,myFrameGray,myFrameEdge;

myFrame1 = imread(framePath,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

cvtColor(myFrame1,myFrameGray,CV_BGR2GRAY);

vector<Vec3f> circles;

Canny( myFrameGray, myFrameEdge, 50, 150, 3);

HoughCircles( myFrameEdge, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, myFrameEdge.rows/10, 100, 9, 50, 90 );

for( int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
{
  Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
  int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);

  string box_text = format("index : %d", i);
  putText(myFrame1, box_text, center, FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0, CV_RGB(0,255,0), 2.0);//afisare index
  circle( myFrame1, center, 3, Scalar(0,0,0), -1, 8, 0 );//centrele cercurilor
  circle( myFrame1, center, radius, Scalar(0,0,0), 3, 8, 0 );//marginile cercurilor
}


float xMassVect[10],yMassVect[10];
int sizeofMass=0;
float xGMass=0,yGMass=0;
float xGmassAns=0,yGmassAns=0;
for( int i = 1; i < circles.size(); i=i+2 )
{

    Point Mass((cvRound(circles[i-1][0])+cvRound(circles[i][0]))/2,(cvRound(circles[i-1][1])+cvRound(circles[i][1]))/2);//masa a doua cate doua cercuri
    circle( myFrame1, Mass, 3, Scalar(0,0,0), -1, 8, 0 );
    sizeofMass=sizeof(Mass.x)-1; //marimea structurii Mass pentru a calcula centrul de greutatate ansamblului ((centru1+centru2+centru3)/3)

}
int k=0;
for (int i=1;i<circles.size();i=i+2)
{
    xMassVect[k]=(cvRound(circles[i-1][0])+cvRound(circles[i][0]))/2;//scrierea coordonatelor x in vector ale lui Mass
    yMassVect[k]=(cvRound(circles[i-1][1])+cvRound(circles[i][1]))/2;//scrierea coordonatelor y in vector ale lui Mass
    xGMass+=xMassVect[k];//suma centrelor de greutate pe x
    yGMass+=yMassVect[k];//suma centrelor de creutate pe y
    k++;
}

for (int k=0;k<circles.size()/2;k++)
{
    cout <<"Coordonate doua cate doua"<<endl;
    cout<<"x["<<k<<"]="<<xMassVect[k];
    cout<<"y["<<k<<"]="<<yMassVect[k];
    cout<<endl;
    xGmassAns+=xMassVect[k];
    yGmassAns+=yMassVect[k];

}
    cout<<"x centruAnsamblu="<<xGmassAns<<endl;
    cout<<"y centruAnsamblu="<<yGmassAns<<endl;

float distance[10];
float sumOfDistance=0;
float optimDistance=0;

for (int k=0;k<circles.size()/2;k++)
{
    distance[k]=sqrt(pow(xMassVect[k]-xGmassAns/(circles.size()/2),2)+pow(yMassVect[k]-yGmassAns/(circles.size()/2),2));//distantele de la centrul ansmblului la centrele cercurilor grupate 2 cate 2
    cout<<"distanta"<<k<<"="<<distance[k]<<endl;
}

for (int i=0;i<circles.size()/2;i++)
{
    sumOfDistance+=distance[i];//suma distantelor
}

    optimDistance=sumOfDistance/sizeofMass;//distanta optima ca medie aritmetica
    cout<<optimDistance;
    Point GmassAns(xGMass/sizeofMass,yGMass/sizeofMass);//centrul de greutate pentru intreg ansamblul
    circle(myFrame1,GmassAns,3,Scalar(10,10,100),-1,8,0);
    circle( myFrame1, GmassAns, optimDistance, Scalar(100,50,50), 3, 8, 0 );



     /// afisare rezultat
    namedWindow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo", myFrame1 );
    imshow( "Hough Circle Transform Edge", myFrameEdge );
    string savePath="D:/frame_1.bmp";
            imwrite(savePath,myFrame1);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;


  }
```

And is any chance to sort the vector with the data of circles by color?
Like :
Two circles in an element of a array : one red and one green, that are near each other ?